# Meta edit buttons disabled and not on main site

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-interface

The edit buttons are disabled on the meta and not main site. Is this status by design or a bug?

[image] [meta link](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2139/6796)

[image] [main link](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12216/sore-on-yorkshire-terrier-external-mouth-chin-visit-to-vet-required)

Comment: By design. Suggested edits don't exist on meta sites, so if you don't have the rep needed, you just can't edit.

Comment: @ArtOfCode ah thanks.  Care to write an answer?